# File size decreased a lot after converting from octet-stream to blob

Tags: javascript, blob

Back-End sends me PDF file (byte Array) with type octet-stream.
On Front-End side I need to convert this octet-stream to Blob and user should be able to download this file and open this PDF in Google Chrome.

But when I received file from back-end, I see the following params of file:

```
{size: 4909, type: octet-stream}
```

After converting stream to Blob I'm getting the following params:

```
Blob(15): {size: 15, type: ""}
```

As you can see, size was decreased a lot, when I'm trying to download the file, I'm getting error, file corrupted.

Code sample:

```
api.get("http://url-example").then(data => {
    // On this step: data = {size: 4909, type: octet-stream}
    let newBlob = new Blob([data]);
    // On this step: newBlob = Blob(15): {size: 15, type: ""}
    const objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
}
```

Comment: Your blob is a text file containing the string `[object Object]`. What is exactly returned by tour fetch method? Can't you even simply make the request's responseType be a blob directly?

Comment: perhaps `data` is already a Blob!

Comment: Fetch method returned byte array ( a lot of symbols).

Comment: @Bravo no it's not a Blob otherwise that would have worked. To Op you mean a String? ByteArray is not a thing in js.

Comment: Of course, you're right @Kaiido - but if the fetch returned a string, that too would work :p

Comment: `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(data))` - what is the output

Comment: @Bravo [object Object]

Comment: but it has a property called `size`, and another called `type`? What other properties does it have

Comment: also it have property: "slice: f"

Comment: What is that `api` you are using? Are there some online documentation about it and its `get` method? I guess if you do `console.log(data instanceof Blob)` it will log `false`, right?